# 9 patch shrinking issue

Tags: android, background, nine-patch

I'm having issues with a 9patch image. The layout is set to 50dp with a 9patch background, but when loaded on small screens the layout is larger than 50dp.

However I have another layout with the same 9patch background (menuBtn) and that doesn't expand so I'm not sure what is making the 9patch misbehave on this one layout.

**SS:**
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuBtn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar"
        android:clickable="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/actionbar_menu"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/div1"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menuBtn"
        android:src="@drawable/actionbar_divider"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**9patch img:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, it's a weird bug? Anyway the 9patch is taller than 50dp on the small screen size so with the base background set to actionbar, it doesn't scale.

However if I nest another RelativeLayout inside the main RelativeLayout and set that background to actionbar, then it scales just fine. Not sure why the original RelativeLayout doesn't.

**Example:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="0dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This code works, so yeah...